# Basic probability

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

> $\text{P}(A \cup B) = 0.7$ and $\text{P}(A\cup B^C) = 0.9.$ Determine $\text{P}(A).$

I have $\text{P}((A\cup B)^C) = 0.3$ and $\text{P}((A\cup B^C)^C) = 0.1$ and then I don't know what to do... I tried looking at the union, but I got confused trying to intersect and union everything together.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is helpful, since intersections are more convenient when we are using a Venn diagram. So draw the usual two intersecting ovals, labelling them $A$ and $B$.

We have $(A\cup B)^c=A^c\cap B^c$. So write $0.3$ in the region which is outside both $A$ and $B$.

We have $(A\cup B^c)^c=A^c\cap B$. So write $0.1$ in the region which is outside $A$ but in $B$.

Together, the two regions you have put numbers into cover everything outside $A$.
Thus $\Pr(A)=1-0.3-0.1$.

Answer (score 0):

$P((A\cup B^C)^C) = 0.1 \implies P(A) = P(A \cup B) - P((A\cup B^C)^C) = 0.6$.  You can see this from a Venn diagram.  $(A\cup B^C)^C$ represents what is in $B$ but not in $A$.